# Can accessors and mutators be used on relationships?

Tags: php, laravel

Can I access values using an accessor on a relationship ? I can use this:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute(){     
    return "$this->name "."$this->surname";
}
```

and then:

```
User::get()->pluck('full_name');
```

but how can I do something like this:

```
$category->users()-get()->pluck('full_name');
```

is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: How are your relationships set up?  belongsToMany or hasMany/BelongsTo and which way?

Comment: @RossWilson its morphedByMany

Comment: Are you getting an error?? If not, what are you getting instead? If you do `dd($category->users()-get())` what do you get?

Comment: I get no errors. 'dd($category->users()-get())' works I get a user collection of the category.

Comment: ...but `$category->users()-get()->pluck('full_name')` doesn't work??

Comment: @RossWilson I got the problem, ıt was a issue with the accessors. now this '$category->users()-get()->pluck('full_name')' works. thx.

Comment: What was your problem with the accessor?

Comment: I used getFullName() instead getFullNameAccessor() after changing that it worked.